# How to layer point feature over a polygon feature

Tags: javascript, maps, polygon, point, azure-maps

How can I get a point feature over a polygon feature? I am layering polygon on top of the point feature or a marker feature however I also have a tooltip (popup) that fires when hovering over the features but only the polygon popup is getting displayed even when I am hovering over the point/marker feature. I am assured the point/marker is over/on top of the polygon because I assigned a 1.0 opacity and point/marker is still visible.

So when a point is on top of a polygon how can I get the popup on the point/marker feature to fire? Or is this a potential defect?

I swapped out the hover event for a 'click' event on the point/marker feature and the popup works as expected but this is not the desired behavior.

TIA!
Rick...

Comment: I have since found out this is expected behavior when features overlap. This is because the event doesn't re-fire when over the point due to the fact the map still sees the cursor as being over the polygon...in essence the cursor never left the polygon layer.
There is a very tiny area of the point that if I hover in just the right spot the point popup will appear but if I move ever so slightly the polygon popup reappears.
Oh well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a bunch of experimenting and its the order in which the events are added that make all the difference, not the order of the layers in this case. Unless you add the events to the map, rather than the individual layers, then the rendering order is used.

I've put together a little test app to test all the different scenarios:

```js
var map, datasource, output, polygonLayer, pointLayer, isSwapped = false;

function GetMap() {
  output = document.getElementById('output');

  //Initialize a map instance.
  map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
    center: [-122.1255, 47.6305],
    zoom: 17,
    view: 'Auto',

    //Add your Azure Maps subscription key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps
    authOptions: {
      authType: 'subscriptionKey',
      subscriptionKey: subscriptionKey
    }
  });

  //Wait until the map resources are ready.
  map.events.add('ready', function() {

    //Create a data source and add it to the map.
    datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
    map.sources.add(datasource);

    //Add polygon to data source.
    datasource.add(new atlas.data.Polygon(
      [
        [
          [-122.126, 47.63096],
          [-122.12602, 47.62997],
          [-122.12537, 47.62994],
          [-122.12534, 47.63094],
          [-122.12600, 47.63096]
        ]
      ]
    ));

    //Add point data
    datasource.add(new atlas.data.Point([-122.1255, 47.6305]));

    polygonLayer = new atlas.layer.PolygonLayer(datasource, null, {
      fillColor: 'red'
    });


    pointLayer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
      filter: ['==', ['geometry-type'], 'Point']
    });

    map.layers.add([polygonLayer, pointLayer]);

    map.events.add('mousemove', layerHovered);
  });
}

function layerHovered(e) {
  var msg = [];

  if (e.shapes && e.shapes.length > 0) {
    msg.push(e.shapes.length, ' shapes hovered.<ul>');

    e.shapes.forEach(s => {
      if (s instanceof atlas.Shape) {
        msg.push('<li>Shape: ', s.getType(), '</li>');
      } else {
        msg.push('<li>Feature: ', s.geometry.type, ' (', s.source, ' -> ', s.sourceLayer, ')</li>');
      }
    });

    msg.push('</ul>');
  }

  output.innerHTML = msg.join('');
}

function swapLayerOrder() {
  map.layers.remove([pointLayer, polygonLayer]);

  if (isSwapped) {

    map.layers.add([polygonLayer, pointLayer]);
  } else {
    map.layers.add([pointLayer, polygonLayer]);
  }

  isSwapped = !isSwapped;
}

function changeEvents(elm) {
  map.events.remove('mousemove', layerHovered);
  map.events.remove('mousemove', pointLayer, layerHovered);
  map.events.remove('mousemove', polygonLayer, layerHovered);

  switch (elm.value) {
    case 'map':
      map.events.add('mousemove', layerHovered);
      break;
    case 'ps':
      map.events.add('mousemove', [polygonLayer, pointLayer], layerHovered);
      break;
    case 'sp':
      map.events.add('mousemove', [pointLayer, polygonLayer], layerHovered);
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body onload="GetMap()">
      <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:600px;"></div>

 <div style="position:absolute;top: 10px;left:10px;background-color:white;padding:10px;">
 
  <input type="button" onclick="swapLayerOrder()" value="Swap layer order"/>
  
  <br/><br/>
  
  Attach event to:<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="map" checked="checked" onclick="changeEvents(this)"/> map<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="ps" onclick="changeEvents(this)"/> polygon layer then symbol layer<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="sp" onclick="changeEvents(this)"/> symbol layer then polygon layer<br/>
  
  <br/>
  
  <div id="output"></div>
 
 </div>
    <script>var subscriptionKey = atob('dFRrMUpWRWFlTnZEa3h4bnhIbTljWWFDdnFsT3ExdS1mWFR2eVhuMlhrQQ==')</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay I managed to take your input and rearrange events on the layers and I am getting good results now. However there is an issue if the point feature is a marker. I am adding a pulsing marker to represent an IoT sensor sending out a signal. I have a popup on that and the layer and event is added after the polygon and point feature that represents a facility (point if zoomed out; polygon when zoomed in) but the marker is on at all zoom levels. Unless I turn polygon off I cannot get the marker to popup info. Would like to add points and then stylize them as a pulsing type marker. Thanks again!

Comment: Markers and popups use traditional DOM elements. These are always rendered above other elements in the map since they can't be rendered in the WebGL canvas. Not sure I understand your issue. I would think that the marker even would be fired first since the mouse would hit it first, but possible the map catches the event and triggers events based on the order they were added. 

Depending on how large your data set is, it is possible to create a pulse effect using a bubble layer with a symbol layer.

Comment: Thanks again! I would love to see how a bubblelayer and symbollayer would be accomplished my dataset is small. In all examples I am finding these comments around event creation: Open the popup on mousemove or touchstart on a shape/symbol layer. Mousemove is used as mouseover only fires when the mouse initially goes over a shape/symbol. If two shapes and/or symbols overlap, moving the mouse from one to the other won't trigger the event for the new shape/symbol as the mouse is still considered over the initial layer.
Again only seems to apply to the marker symbol...points and polygons no issue

Comment: I put together a sample and found that it works with large data sets too (tried up to 100K points). You can find the sample here: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Pulse%20animation%20with%20bubble%20layer

Comment: Thank you so much...simply AWESOME!